# Add custom sorting algorithm to TableColumn

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview

here's my problem:

*Set a custom sorting algorithm for the default sorting of a `TableColumn`.*

**Background**:
As an example column, I want to use a column that represents IPv4 addresses as a `String`. So the default sorting is lexicographic (1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.10, 1.1.1.2). But I would like to have a numerical sorting (1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.10).

The sorting algorithm is not the problem. I can trigger this sorting with a `Button` and the display in the `TableView` is correct. But what I want to do is to click on the column header and thereby call up my sorting algorithm.

**General conditions**:
The data in the table is in an `ObservableList`, which is wrapped in a `SortedList`.

My question at this point is: How can I realize this?

Comment: Yoou can determine the sorting order specifying a custom comparator, but you cannot change the sorting algorithm using the types you mention. Probably it"s most convenitent to use the [`comparator` property of `TableColumn`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#comparatorProperty) which ramoves the need to place additional controls in the scene and simply use the column headers for sorting.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your comparators. When you click on a column's header, the column's comparator will be used, if you click again, the reversed order of that comparator will be used. If you're using a `SortedList`, and you have a different comparator for each column, bind the comparator property of the list to the table's comparator property. This way, when you click on the header, your list will also be notified and your data will be updated:

```java
columnA.setComparator(comparator1);
columnB.setComparator(comparator2);
columnC.setComparator(comparator3);

ObservableList<MyData> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
SortedList<MyData> sortedList = new SortedList<>(items);
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());

tableView.setItems(sortedList);
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks.

Comment: which you could have found yourself by simply reading the api doc of TableColumn/Base and TableView .. just saying ;)